# Tinymce html2pdf

Tags: pdf, fonts, tinymce

I have been searching for this but i can't start coding or change configuration because i can't quite understand the concept. Can you help me know where to start?

i have a tinymce editor with different fonts. When i saved it the the text(with its font) was saved in html format. I am converting the html format to pdf by using html2pdf plug in but there was an "TCDPF Error: can not include ''". I have tested all the fonts in my tinymce editor but only Arial works with the html2pdf. I know that you can set the font in html2pdf by using

```
 $html2pdf->pdf->setFont('calibri');
```

but this means the text will be saved in one font only. Here comes my problem because in my text each word has different fonts. What should i do? i appreciate any help. :) please understand, i am just a novice

Answer (score 0):

I would use some other tool to create a pdf, what about a ghostscript solution?